# Change image/plot by clicking link/button?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, interaction

I have a series of images I want to make interactive. As an example let us say I have three images: a cat, a dog and a mouse.

I want have all three in a single figure in my document, but not shown simultaneously. In fact, I want the reader to be able to click on corresponding text to change the image. So: The same figure with clickable areas in the image - or text beneath. When clicked the image changes, like in the mockup below.

I know interactive videos, 3D models and questionnaires can be made using LaTeX. Can something like this also be done? I am guessing PDF layers and pgf/tikz might do it, but I am unsure as to *how*

[image: Mockup]

Comment: PDF Layers via pkg `ocgx2` could be an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be achieved with PDF Layers via package `ocgx2`. Note the use of the common option `radiobtngrp` to make the visibility of the grouped layers mutually exclusive.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{ocgx2}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \makebox[0pt][l]{%
    \begin{ocg}[radiobtngrp=letters]{A}{A}{on}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{ocg}
  }%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{%
    \begin{ocg}[radiobtngrp=letters]{B}{B}{off}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \end{ocg}
  }%
  \begin{ocg}[radiobtngrp=letters]{C}{C}{off}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
  \end{ocg}
  
  \showocg{A}{Letter ``A''}\quad
  \showocg{B}{Letter ``B''}\quad
  \showocg{C}{Letter ``C''}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```